# Armazenar valores de uma string em um vetor

Tags: c

Preciso fazer um programa em C que recebe uma sequência de números, guarda os valores em um vetor e depois imprime essa sequência na ordem inversa. Ele deve receber duas entradas, a primeira é um número inteiro que indica quantos números a sequência possui, e a segunda é a sequência dos números (cada número é separado apenas por um 'espaço em branco'), como segue no exemplo:

```
4

2 51 8 10
```

Para ler a string pensei em usar a função:

```
char sequencia[100]; 

scanf("%[^\n]",sequencia);
```

Porém não estou conseguindo separar os valores e armazenar dentro de um vetor de inteiros. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Por que ler como string ? use scanf("%d")

Comment: usando scanf(%d) como faço para que cada valor seja armazenado no vetor em uma posição diferente? obs: a sequência é passada para o programa em uma única string, sendo que cada valor está separado por um 'espaço' apenas

Comment: é obrigatório que os números estejam separados por espaços? Os números não poderiam ser digitados separadamente?

Comment: Crie um array de tamanho 100 (estou assumindo 100 por que voce usou no tamanho da sua string) para valores int ... e use uma variável que representa um índice no array (começa seu valor em 0 ... e vai incrementando para cada valor lido ...)... scanf("%d", sequencia[i]); ++i;

Comment: a questão pede que eles estejam separados por espaços apenas, o único jeito que pensei em fazer isso era ler como uma string e separar os valores usando o espaço como delimitador

Answer (score 1):

Para responder à tua pergunta: usa [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) para ler strings com espaços.

Atenção que o `fgets()` guarda o ENTER final de cada linha. Se for necessário limpa esse ENTER antes de processares mais a string.

```
char input[100];
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) /* erro */;
/* se necessario remove ENTER final de input */
```

---

Mas, para as tuas necessidades, podes usar a conversão `"%d"` do `scanf()`, que lê os caracteres e interpreta como número automaticamente:

```
int n;
int k;
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) /* erro */; // primeiro número
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    if (scanf("%d", &sequencia[k]) != 1) /* erro */; // números seguintes
}
```

Nota: para o `scanf()` com formato `"%d"` os espaços, os ENTERs, os TABs anteriores ao numero são ignorados automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Caso os valores que você tenha que recolher sejam apenas inteiros, você pode fazer assim:

```
...
int *y;
int x,i;
if(scanf("%i", &x); != -1){
    y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); // Aloca um tamanho para y
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        scanf("%i", &y[i]);
}
...
```

Comment: O *cast* (conversão explicita) ao valor devolvido pelo `malloc()` é, quando muito, redundante; e pode esconder um erro que o compilador apanharia na sua ausência.